# Totally geodesic hypersurface on high dimensional sphere near round metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, spheres, geodesic

Let $g$ be a metric $C^2$-close enough to the round metric $g_0$. Can we still guarantee the existence of totally geodesic hypersurface for the metric $g$. Maybe some embedded $S^{n-1}$... I slightly know the existence of closed geodesic using min-max and seem like this cannot be extended to the higher dimensional sphere.

Comment: Not in general.  This is a relatively recent result of Wilhelm and Murphy.  I will try to dig up the reference tomorrow morning.

Comment: @JasonDevito Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here you go:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.09240.pdf, T. Murphy and F. Wilhelm  Random manifolds have no totally geodesic submanifolds, Michigan Mathematical Journal,  68 (2019), 323–335.